# Event handler for jQuery works great but shouldn't because it's not in ready() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I've made a mistake and placed the event handler for all links with class *cancelAction* outside of the function that's executed as the document loads, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });

$(".cancelAction").on("click", function () { ... });
```

To my surprise, it works still! I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to. Am I wrong?

I've triple-checked that commenting out the handler voids the functionality. I can't understand for my life how the browser knows that this specific handler is to be regarded, if it doesn't get attached to any scope (since it's not being executed within `ready(...)` function.

Comment: Is your jQuery code at the end of the document?

Comment: If the script is placed after the `.cancelAction` element(s) are parsed by the browser, this should work fine.

Comment: If it's directly before the closing body tag this is expected behavior. It's just about if the DOM is loaded when the script is run.

Comment: @Barmar It's at the top **but** it's a partial view. JavaScript, you fooled me again!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have this code after document elements loaded then it should world as the code executes after dom elements are loaded. like:

```
....
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".cancelAction").on("click", function () { ... });
</script>
```

This code would work as all elements are loaded when the code executes.

Comment: Oh, sneaky one... The script is at the top of the file **but** it's a partial view, so technically speaking, the body tag is before it. Nice...